# I want to convert date time into 6 digit number, then convert it back into the exact date time. Is there a encryption method to this?

Tags: c++, encryption, encode, checksum, crc

Here are what I want do (1) convert date time to 6digit number ;(2)convert the 6digit number to the input date time. Any suggestion to do this?

Comment: Can you write some example? What language you want to use?

Comment: C or c++. I may add passphrase for the conversion.

Comment: For example, I have date time 08/01 2015 07:48. I want to convert it to a unique 6 digit. Someone can convert back to the same date time.

Comment: That's too much information to be contained in a 6 digit number. There are going to be collisions.

Comment: If this does not work, I have to calculate the Crc value of year, month, and days, then hash the results into 2 digits. The hours and mins are converted into a unique 4 digits.

Comment: There are 86400 seconds in just one day. That's five digits. You already used up five of your six digits just for the time portion. It would be logically impossible to use a single digit to express a date range, in your situation that's longer than eleven days. Simple math proves what you're trying to do is logically impossible.

Comment: There is a way !!  :)

Comment: I have a ready solution written in python. do you care about it ? or should i convert it to C for you >??

Comment: What is the limit on the dates? 1 Jan 1AD to the present? 1 Jan 2000 to 31 Dec 2044? The length of the range will determine whether this is possible.

Comment: From current time to 2100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below is a python script that uses gtk (on linux) that I prepared for exactly the same purpose. If you are interested, I can convert it to C, or you can try to do so...
In order to try it, input the date as `YYMMDDHHmmss` then click the convert button, ... very handy !!

**The only thing, I had to use numbers and letters !!!!!**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import sys
import pygtk
pygtk.require ( '2.0' )
import gtk

def to_digit(a):
    if (a < 10) and (a >= 0):
        return chr(48 + a)
    elif (a < 36) and (a > 9):
        return chr(55 + a)
    elif (a < 60) and (a > 35):
        return chr(61 + a)
    else:
        return chr(95)
#

def to_int(c):
    if (ord(c) < 58) and (ord(c) > 47):
        return ord(c)-48
    elif (ord(c) < 91) and (ord(c) > 64):
        return ord(c)-55
    elif (ord(c) < 123) and (ord(c) > 96):
        return ord(c)-61
#

def m_call(a):
    st = ''
    if a == 0:
        return '0'
    while a:
        b = a % 100
        a = a / 100
        st = to_digit(b) + st
    return st
#

def rev_m_call(st):
    cumul = 0
    for i in range(len(st)):
        cumul += to_int(st[i:i+1])*pow(10,2*(len(st)-i-1))
    return cumul
#

class frmMain:

    def run_cmd(self, widget, data=None):
        if data == 'o1':
            self.output_entry.set_text (m_call(int(self.input_entry.get_text())))
        elif data == 'o2':
            self.input_entry.set_text (str(rev_m_call(self.output_entry.get_text())))
        elif data == 'c':
            self.input_entry.set_text ("")
            self.output_entry.set_text ("")
        else:
            pass

    def delete_event(self, widget, event, data=None):
        print ("delete event occurred")
        return False

    def destroy(self, widget, data=None):
        gtk.main_quit ()

    def __init__(self):

        self.WIDTH  = 300
        self.HEIGHT = 60

        self.window = gtk.Window ( gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL )
        self.window.set_title ( "Give the date to convert to code!!" )
        self.window.set_size_request ( self.WIDTH, self.HEIGHT )
        self.window.set_resizable ( False )
        self.window.connect ( "delete_event", self.delete_event )
        self.window.connect ( "destroy", self.destroy )
        self.window.set_border_width ( 2 )
        vb = gtk.VBox ( False, 0 )
        self.window.add ( vb )
        hb = gtk.HBox ( True, 0 )
        self.input_entry = gtk.Entry ()
        hb.pack_start ( self.input_entry, False, True, 2 )
        self.output_entry = gtk.Entry ()
        hb.pack_start (self.output_entry, False, True, 2 )
        vb.pack_start ( hb, False, True, 2 )
        hb = gtk.HBox ( False, 0 )
        r1 = gtk.Button ( ">======->>" )
        r1.connect ( "clicked", self.run_cmd, 'o1' )
        hb.pack_end ( r1, False, False, 2 )
        r2 = gtk.Button ( "<<-======<" )
        r2.connect ( "clicked", self.run_cmd, 'o2' )
        hb.pack_end ( r2, False, False, 2 )
        clear_button = gtk.Button ( "Clear" )
        clear_button.connect ( "clicked", self.run_cmd, 'c' )
        hb.pack_end ( clear_button, False, False, 2 )
        cancel_button = gtk.Button ( "Cancel" )
        cancel_button.connect ( "clicked", self.destroy )
        hb.pack_end ( cancel_button, False, False, 2 )
        vb.pack_start ( hb, False, True, 2 )
        self.window.show_all ()

    def main(self):
        gtk.main()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    run = frmMain ()
    run.main ()
```

Comment: I will try to understand the code and do some testing on Monday. Thanks.

Comment: I have hard time to convert the code into C or C++. It would be nice to convert the functions to c.

Comment: Give me few minutes..

Comment: This post is put on hold... I cannot answer it more here... I have pasted the answer in C language to pastebin .. cheers.. http://pastebin.com/3xADXpi3

Comment: It's not a "6digit number" but a "6 character string".